# Is it possible to setup correctly a concealed (indoor) door closer for multiple situations?

Tags: doors

Let's consider a concealed door closer (closes the door after you open it).

Concealed means it is put inside the door itself (it's kind of 
invisible).

Here is an example to have some idea:

[image]

I can perfectly tune it, but when the balcony door is also open, it won't be able to close the main door.
(because of wind-blast)

And if I tune it for the wind-blast situation it will slam the door if the balcony is closed.

Is there any way to tune these stuff perfectly for these two situations?

Comment: Probably yes, I think that there are commercial applications where this is done

Comment: Depends on the details of the closer - most have one control/adjustment for main force and another for final closing, and getting them set correctly means the main one will have lots of  force but there will be no slam if the final one takes over and gently finishes the job. But the specific details of how to adjust the two and how they interact vary with the specific models of door closer - and some will do better than others, in a manner than might or might not follow their prices. Some may not even have two controls, but casually, the one pictured appears to.

Comment: I have two controls very similar to the attached picture, but my problem is that if I finetune it for the 'no-wind-blast' situation, it works perfectly, but then when there is blast, it won't close. On the other hand, if I tune it for the blast situation, it will slam the door. So basically how to set it correctly? A.) allow a large main force and set the final closing accordingly, or B.) set a lower main force, and don't brake too much at the end?

Comment: For the main force screw I need to turn it 3 times around for working correctly in the 'blast' situation, that's a huge power change!